# apt-get install wants remove everything

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt, aptitude

First thing is, when I try to install teamviewer (`https://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_i386.deb`)
it wasnt install fully so i use `apt-get install -f` but `-f` delete all packages, after that I restore the os from backup.

Now ,I want to install wine but:

```
trys34e@trys34e:~$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 2.0.2~xenial)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

for -f :

```
trys34e@trys34e:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.8.0-58 linux-headers-4.8.0-58-generic
  linux-image-4.8.0-58-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-58-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

for aptitude: (same problem in teamviewer)

```
trys34e@trys34e:~$ sudo aptitude  install wine
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-horai-umefont{a} fonts-unfonts-core{a} gcc-5-base:i386{a} gcc-6-base:i386{a} libasn1-8-heimdal:i386{a} libasound2:i386{a} libasound2-plugins:i386{a} libasyncns0:i386{a} libavahi-client3:i386{a} libavahi-common-data:i386{a} libavahi-common3:i386{a} 
  libbsd0:i386{a} libc6:i386{a} libcapi20-3{a} libcapi20-3:i386{a} libcomerr2:i386{a} libcups2:i386{a} libdb5.3:i386{a} libdbus-1-3:i386{a} libdrm-amdgpu1:i386{a} libdrm-intel1:i386{a} libdrm-nouveau2:i386{a} libdrm-radeon1:i386{a} libdrm2:i386{a} libedit2:i386{a} 
  libelf1:i386{a} libexif12:i386{a} libexpat1:i386{a} libffi6:i386{a} libflac8:i386{a} libfontconfig1:i386{ab} libfreetype6:i386{a} libgcc1:i386{a} libgcrypt20:i386{ab} libgd3:i386{a} libgif7:i386{a} libgl1-mesa-dri:i386{a} libgl1-mesa-glx:i386{a} 
  libglapi-mesa:i386{a} libglu1-mesa:i386{a} libgmp10:i386{a} libgnutls30:i386{ab} libgpg-error0:i386{a} libgphoto2-6:i386{a} libgphoto2-port12:i386{a} libgpm2:i386{a} libgssapi-krb5-2:i386{ab} libgssapi3-heimdal:i386{a} libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386{a} libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386{a} libhogweed4:i386{a} libhx509-5-heimdal:i386{a} libice6:i386{a} libicu55:i386{a} libidn11:i386{a} libieee1284-3:i386{a} libjack-jackd2-0:i386{a} libjbig0:i386{a} libjpeg-turbo8:i386{a} libjpeg8:i386{a} 
  libjson-c2:i386{a} libk5crypto3:i386{ab} libkeyutils1:i386{a} libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386{a} libkrb5-3:i386{ab} libkrb5support0:i386{ab} liblcms2-2:i386{a} libldap-2.4-2:i386{a} libllvm4.0:i386{a} libltdl7:i386{a} liblzma5:i386{a} libmpg123-0:i386{a} 
  libncurses5:i386{a} libnettle6:i386{a} libodbc1{a} libogg0:i386{a} libopenal1:i386{a} libosmesa6{a} libosmesa6:i386{a} libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386{a} libp11-kit0:i386{a} libpciaccess0:i386{a} libpcre3:i386{a} libpng12-0:i386{a} libpulse0:i386{a} 
  libroken18-heimdal:i386{a} libsamplerate0:i386{a} libsane:i386{a} libsasl2-2:i386{a} libsasl2-modules:i386{a} libsasl2-modules-db:i386{a} libselinux1:i386{a} libsensors4:i386{a} libsm6:i386{a} libsndfile1:i386{a} libspeexdsp1:i386{a} libsqlite3-0:i386{a} 
  libssl1.0.0:i386{a} libstdc++6:i386{a} libsystemd0:i386{a} libtasn1-6:i386{ab} libtiff5:i386{a} libtinfo5:i386{a} libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386{a} libudev1:i386{a} libusb-1.0-0:i386{a} libuuid1:i386{a} libv4l-0:i386{a} libv4lconvert0:i386{a} libvorbis0a:i386{a} 
  libvorbisenc2:i386{a} libwebp5:i386{a} libwind0-heimdal:i386{a} libwrap0:i386{a} libx11-6:i386{a} libx11-xcb1:i386{a} libxau6:i386{a} libxcb-dri2-0:i386{a} libxcb-dri3-0:i386{a} libxcb-glx0:i386{a} libxcb-present0:i386{a} libxcb-sync1:i386{a} libxcb1:i386{a} 
  libxcomposite1:i386{a} libxcursor1:i386{a} libxdamage1:i386{a} libxdmcp6:i386{a} libxext6:i386{a} libxfixes3:i386{a} libxi6:i386{a} libxinerama1:i386{a} libxml2:i386{a} libxpm4:i386{a} libxrandr2:i386{a} libxrender1:i386{a} libxshmfence1:i386{a} libxslt1.1:i386{a} 
  libxt6:i386{a} libxxf86vm1:i386{a} ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386{a} odbcinst{a} odbcinst1debian2{a} p11-kit-modules:i386{a} unixodbc{a} wine wine-gecko2.21{a} wine-gecko2.21:i386{a} wine-mono0.0.8{a} wine1.6{a} wine1.6-amd64{a} wine1.6-i386:i386{a} winetricks{a} 
  zlib1g:i386{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 154 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 192 MB of archives. After unpacking 747 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libkrb5-3 : Breaks: libkrb5-3:i386 (!= 1.15.1-2) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed.
 libkrb5-3:i386 : Breaks: libkrb5-3 (!= 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 1.15.1-2 is installed.
 libgssapi-krb5-2 : Breaks: libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 (!= 1.15.1-2) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed.
 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 : Breaks: libgssapi-krb5-2 (!= 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 1.15.1-2 is installed.
 libk5crypto3 : Breaks: libk5crypto3:i386 (!= 1.15.1-2) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed.
 libk5crypto3:i386 : Breaks: libk5crypto3 (!= 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 1.15.1-2 is installed.
 libkrb5support0 : Breaks: libkrb5support0:i386 (!= 1.15.1-2) but 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2 is to be installed.
 libkrb5support0:i386 : Breaks: libkrb5support0 (!= 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 1.15.1-2 is installed.
 libgcrypt20 : Breaks: libgcrypt20:i386 (!= 1.7.9-1) but 1.6.5-2ubuntu0.3 is to be installed.
 libgcrypt20:i386 : Breaks: libgcrypt20 (!= 1.6.5-2ubuntu0.3) but 1.7.9-1 is installed.
 libfontconfig1 : Breaks: libfontconfig1:i386 (!= 2.12.3-0.2) but 2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed.
 libfontconfig1:i386 : Depends: fontconfig-config:i386 (= 2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1) which is a virtual package, provided by:
              - fontconfig-config, but 2.12.3-0.2 is installed.              - fontconfig-config, but 2.12.3-0.2 is installed.              - fontconfig-config, but 2.12.3-0.2 is installed.
    Breaks: libfontconfig1 (!= 2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1) but 2.12.3-0.2 is installed.
 libgnutls30 : Breaks: libgnutls30:i386 (!= 3.5.15-2) but 3.4.10-4ubuntu1.3 is to be installed.
 libgnutls30:i386 : Breaks: libgnutls30 (!= 3.4.10-4ubuntu1.3) but 3.5.15-2 is installed.
 libtasn1-6 : Breaks: libtasn1-6:i386 (!= 4.12-2.1) but 4.7-3ubuntu0.16.04.2 is to be installed.
 libtasn1-6:i386 : Breaks: libtasn1-6 (!= 4.7-3ubuntu0.16.04.2) but 4.12-2.1 is installed.
open: 787; closed: 4348; defer: 357; conflict: 559            .The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

       Remove the following packages:                  
       1)       adwaita-icon-theme         
       2)       apache2 
       3)       apache2-bin     
       4)       apt-transport-https        
       5)       atom    
       6)       autopsy 
       7)       avahi-daemon    
       8)       avahi-utils     
       9)       backbox-artwork 
       10)      backbox-core    
       11)      backbox-default-settings   
       12)      backbox-desktop 
       13)      backbox-forensics-analysis 
       14)      backbox-information-gathering      
       15)      backbox-miscellaneous      
       16)      backbox-mobile-analysis    
       17)      backbox-privilege-escalation       
       18)      backbox-reverse-engineering
       19)      backbox-social-engineering 
       20)      backbox-vulnerability-assessment   
       21)      backbox-wireless-analysis  
       22)      beef-project    
       23)      bind9-host      
       24)      bleachbit       
       25)      blender 
       26)      blueman 
       27)      bluez-cups      
       28)      bluez-obexd     
       29)      brackets
       30)      ca-certificates-java       
       31)      caprine 
       32)      catfish 
       33)      chromium-browser
       34)      chromium-browser-l10n      
       35)      cmake   
       36)      cups    
       37)      cups-browsed    
       38)      cups-bsd
       39)      cups-client     
       40)      cups-core-drivers          
       41)      cups-daemon     
       42)      cups-filters    
       43)      cups-filters-core-drivers  
       44)      cups-ppdc       
       45)      curl    
       46)      default-jre     
       47)      default-jre-headless       
       48)      dex2jar 
       49)      dirmngr 
       50)      discord 
       51)      dissy   
       52)      dnsutils
       53)      driftnet
       54)      ettercap-common 
       55)      ettercap-graphical         
       56)      evince  
       57)      exo-utils       
       58)      file-roller     
       59)      firefox 
       60)      flashplugin-installer      
       61)      fwupd   
       62)      gconf-service   
       63)      gconf-service-backend      
       64)      gconf2  
       65)      gcr     
       66)      gdebi   
       67)      geany   
       68)      ghex    
       69)      ghostscript     
       70)      ghostscript-x   
       71)      gigolo  
       72)      gimp    
       73)      gip     
       74)      gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1   
       75)      gir1.2-cheese-3.0          
       76)      gir1.2-clutter-1.0         
       77)      gir1.2-gtk-3.0  
       78)      gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0      
       79)      gir1.2-gtksource-3.0       
       80)      gir1.2-nautilus-3.0        
       81)      gir1.2-soup-2.4 
       82)      gir1.2-vte-2.91 
       83)      gir1.2-webkit2-4.0         
       84)      gir1.2-wnck-3.0 
       85)      git     
       86)      gitkraken       
       87)      gksu    
       88)      glib-networking 
       89)      gnome-calculator
       90)      gnome-icon-theme
       91)      gnome-icon-theme-symbolic  
       92)      gnome-keyring   
       93)      gnome-system-tools         
       94)      gnome-themes-standard      
       95)      gnome-themes-standard-data 
       96)      gnupg-agent     
       97)      gnupg2  
       98)      gparted 
       99)      greybird-gtk-theme         
       100)     gstreamer1.0-libav         
       101)     gstreamer1.0-nice          
       102)     gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad   
       103)     gstreamer1.0-plugins-good  
       104)     gtk-recordmydesktop        
       105)     gtk-theme-config
       106)     gtk2-engines-murrine       
       107)     gtk2-engines-pixbuf        
       108)     gtkhash 
       109)     gucharmap       
       110)     gvfs-backends   
       111)     hplip   
       112)     humanity-icon-theme        
       113)     hydra   
       114)     hydra-gtk       
       115)     indicator-application      
       116)     iputils-ping    
       117)     jd-gui  
       118)     katepart
       119)     kde-baseapps-bin
       120)     kde-runtime     
       121)     kdelibs-bin     
       122)     kdelibs5-plugins
       123)     kdoctools       
       124)     kerneloops-daemon          
       125)     kopete  
       126)     krb5-multidev   
       127)     language-selector-gnome    
       128)     libafflib0v5    
       129)     libapache2-mod-php         
       130)     libapache2-mod-php5.6      
       131)     libapache2-mod-php7.1      
       132)     libappindicator1
       133)     libappindicator3-1         
       134)     libappstream-glib8         
       135)     libaprutil1-ldap
       136)     libavahi-ui-gtk3-0         
       137)     libavdevice-ffmpeg56       
       138)     libavfilter-ffmpeg5        
       139)     libavformat-ffmpeg56       
       140)     libbind9-140    
       141)     libcamel-1.2-54 
       142)     libcanberra-gtk3-0         
       143)     libcanberra-gtk3-module    
       144)     libcheese8      
       145)     libclutter-1.0-0
       146)     libclutter-gst-3.0-0       
       147)     libclutter-gtk-1.0-0       
       148)     libcmis-0.5-5v5 
       149)     libcryptui0a    
       150)     libcups2
       151)     libcupscgi1     
       152)     libcupsfilters1 
       153)     libcupsimage2   
       154)     libcupsmime1    
       155)     libcupsppdc1    
       156)     libcurl3
       157)     libcurl3-gnutls 
       158)     libcurl4-openssl-dev       
       159)     libdns162       
       160)     libebackend-1.2-10         
       161)     libebook-1.2-16 
       162)     libebook-contacts-1.2-2    
       163)     libedata-book-1.2-25       
       164)     libedataserver-1.2-21      
       165)     libevdocument3-4
       166)     libevview3-3    
       167)     libexo-1-0      
       168)     libfarstream-0.2-5         
       169)     libfreerdp-plugins-standard
       170)     libgadu3
       171)     libgail-3-0     
       172)     libgarcon-1-0   
       173)     libgcr-ui-3-1   
       174)     libgdata22      
       175)     libgimp2.0      
       176)     libgksu2-0      
       177)     libglade2-0     
       178)     libgnome-desktop-3-12      
       179)     libgnutls-openssl27        
       180)     libgnutls30     
       181)     libgpgme++2v5   
       182)     libgpgme11      
       183)     libgs9  
       184)     libgssapi-krb5-2
       185)     libgssdp-1.0-3  
       186)     libgssrpc4      
       187)     libgtk-3-0      
       188)     libgtk-3-bin    
       189)     libgtk-3-common 
       190)     libgtk2-gladexml-perl      
       191)     libgtk2-perl    
       192)     libgtk2.0-0     
       193)     libgtk2.0-bin   
       194)     libgtkglext1    
       195)     libgtkhex-3-0   
       196)     libgtkmm-2.4-1v5
       197)     libgtkmm-3.0-1v5
       198)     libgtksourceview-3.0-1     
       199)     libgtksourceview2.0-0      
       200)     libgtkspell0    
       201)     libgtkspell3-3-0
       202)     libgucharmap-2-90-7        
       203)     libgupnp-1.0-4  
       204)     libgupnp-igd-1.0-4         
       205)     libido3-0.1-0   
       206)     libimobiledevice6          
       207)     libindicator3-7 
       208)     libindicator7   
       209)     libisccfg140    
       210)     libk5crypto3    
       211)     libkabc4
       212)     libkadm5clnt-mit11         
       213)     libkadm5srv-mit11          
       214)     libkatepartinterfaces4     
       215)     libkdb5-8       
       216)     libkde3support4 
       217)     libkdewebkit5   
       218)     libkemoticons4  
       219)     libkeybinder0   
       220)     libkfile4       
       221)     libkhtml5       
       222)     libkio5 
       223)     libkldap4       
       224)     libkmediaplayer4
       225)     libknewstuff2-4 
       226)     libknewstuff3-4 
       227)     libknotifyconfig4          
       228)     libkopete4      
       229)     libkparts4      
       230)     libkpimidentities4         
       231)     libkpimtextedit4
       232)     libkpimutils4   
       233)     libkrb5-3       
       234)     libktexteditor4 
       235)     libkxmlrpcclient4          
       236)     libldap-2.4-2   
       237)     libldb1 
       238)     libnautilus-extension1a    
       239)     libneon27-gnutls
       240)     libnepomuk4     
       241)     libnepomukquery4a          
       242)     libnepomukutils4
       243)     libnfsidmap2    
       244)     libnice10       
       245)     libnm-glib-vpn1 
       246)     libnm-glib4     
       247)     libnm-gtk0      
       248)     libnm-util2     
       249)     libnm0  
       250)     libnma0 
       251)     libnss-mdns     
       252)     liboauth0       
       253)     libopenconnect5 
       254)     libopencv-contrib2.4v5     
       255)     libopencv-highgui2.4v5     
       256)     libopencv-legacy2.4v5      
       257)     libopencv-objdetect2.4v5   
       258)     libopenimageio1.6          
       259)     libplasma3      
       260)     libpq-dev       
       261)     libpq5  
       262)     libpurple-bin   
       263)     libpurple0      
       264)     libqcustomplot1.3          
       265)     libqt5printsupport5        
       266)     libqt5scintilla2-12v5      
       267)     libraptor2-0    
       268)     librasqal3      
       269)     librdf0 
       270)     libreoffice-base-core      
       271)     libreoffice-calc
       272)     libreoffice-core
       273)     libreoffice-gtk 
       274)     libreoffice-help-en-us     
       275)     libreoffice-math
       276)     libreoffice-writer         
       277)     librest-0.7-0   
       278)     librtmp1
       279)     libsane-hpaio   
       280)     libserf-1-1     
       281)     libsmbclient    
       282)     libsoprano4     
       283)     libsoup-gnome2.4-1         
       284)     libsoup2.4-1    
       285)     libspectre1     
       286)     libssh-4
       287)     libssh-gcrypt-4 

              Keep the following packages at their current version:   
       479)     libasound2-plugins:i386 [Not Installed]       
       480)     libavahi-client3:i386 [Not Installed]         
       481)     libcups2:i386 [Not Installed]      
       482)     libdbus-1-3:i386 [Not Installed]   
       483)     libfontconfig1:i386 [Not Installed]
       484)     libgcrypt20:i386 [Not Installed]   
       485)     libgd3:i386 [Not Installed]
       486)     libgnutls30:i386 [Not Installed]   
       487)     libgphoto2-6:i386 [Not Installed]  
       488)     libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 [Not Installed]         
       489)     libk5crypto3:i386 [Not Installed]  
       490)     libkrb5-3:i386 [Not Installed]     
       491)     libkrb5support0:i386 [Not Installed]          
       492)     libldap-2.4-2:i386 [Not Installed] 
       493)     libpulse0:i386 [Not Installed]     
       494)     libsane:i386 [Not Installed]       
       495)     libsystemd0:i386 [Not Installed]   
       496)     libtasn1-6:i386 [Not Installed]    
       497)     libxslt1.1:i386 [Not Installed]    
       498)     p11-kit-modules:i386 [Not Installed]          
       499)     wine [Not Installed]       
       500)     wine1.6 [Not Installed]    
       501)     wine1.6-amd64 [Not Installed]      
       502)     wine1.6-i386:i386 [Not Installed]  
       503)     winetricks [Not Installed] 

              Leave the following dependencies unresolved:    
       504)     foomatic-db-compressed-ppds recommends cups-filters (>= 1.0.42) | foomatic-filters (>= 4.0) 
       505)     foomatic-db-compressed-ppds recommends ghostscript    
       506)     foomatic-db-compressed-ppds recommends cups   
       507)     foomatic-db-compressed-ppds recommends cups-client    
       508)     gnupg2 recommends dirmngr (>= 2.1.0~)         
       509)     hyphen-en-us recommends libreoffice-writer | openoffice.org-writer       
       510)     indicator-messages recommends indicator-applet | indicator-renderer      

       527)     ssh-import-id recommends openssh-server       
       528)     ubuntu-standard recommends apt-transport-https
       529)     ubuntu-standard recommends ntfs-3g 
       530)     ubuntu-standard recommends openssh-client     
       531)     udisks2 recommends ntfs-3g 
       532)     binwalk recommends sleuthkit       
       533)     bluez-tools recommends bluez-obexd 
       534)     gksu recommends gnome-keyring      
       535)     guymager recommends gksu   
       536)     junit recommends default-jre (>= 1.4) | default-jre-headless (>= 1.4) | java2-runtime | java2-runtime-headless 
       537)     libproxychains3 recommends dnsutils
       538)     macchanger-gtk recommends gksu     
       539)     mat recommends gir1.2-gtk-3.0      
       540)     mat recommends gir1.2-nautilus-3.0      
       541)     mat recommends python-nautilus    
       549)     thunar-archive-plugin recommends xarchiver (>= 0.3.9.2beta2-2) | ark | file-roller | engrampa          
       550)     xfce4-power-manager-data recommends xfce4-power-manager          
       551)     xfce4-screenshooter recommends xfce4-panel (>= 4.11)  
       552)     xfce4-screenshooter recommends xfce4-panel (< 4.13)   
       553)     xfce4-session recommends xscreensaver | light-locker  
       554)     libopenal1:i386 recommends libpulse0:i386 (>= 0.99.1) 
       555)     ubuntu-restricted-addons recommends flashplugin-installer        
       556)     ubuntu-restricted-addons recommends gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad     
       557)     ubuntu-restricted-addons recommends gstreamer1.0-libav
       558)     cups recommends printer-driver-gutenprint     
       559)     cups-daemon recommends cups-browsed
       560)     file-roller recommends sessioninstaller       
       561)     file-roller recommends yelp
       562)     glib-networking-common recommends glib-networking     
       563)     glib-networking-services recommends glib-networking   
       564)     gnome-calculator recommends yelp   
       565)     imagemagick-6.q16 recommends ghostscript      
       566)     libappindicator1 recommends indicator-application (>= 0.2.93)    
       567)     libappindicator3-1 recommends indicator-application (>= 0.2.93)  
       568)     libgtk-3-common recommends libgtk-3-0         
       569)     libgtk2.0-common recommends libgtk2.0-0       
       570)     libmagickcore-6.q16-2 recommends ghostscript  
       571)     libreoffice-common recommends python3-uno (>= 4.4.0~beta2)       
       572)     libreoffice-help-en-us recommends libreoffice-core (> 1:5.1.4) | language-support-translations-en      
       573)     libreoffice-writer recommends libreoffice-math
       574)     libupower-glib3 recommends upower (> 0.99)    
       575)     lightdm recommends unity-greeter | lightdm-greeter | lightdm-kde-greeter 
       576)     network-manager recommends network-manager-pptp       
       577)     network-manager recommends network-manager-gnome | plasma-widget-networkmanagement | plasma-nm         
       578)     network-manager-gnome recommends notification-daemon  
       579)     network-manager-gnome recommends gnome-keyring
       580)     openssh-sftp-server recommends openssh-server | ssh-server       
       581)     update-manager recommends software-properties-gtk (>= 0.71.2)    
       582)     update-manager recommends libgtk2-perl        
       583)     update-notifier recommends python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets | synaptic (>= 0.75.12)    
       584)     update-notifier recommends software-properties-gtk    
       585)     gimp recommends ghostscript
       586)     gimp-data recommends gimp  
       587)     phpmyadmin recommends apache2 | lighttpd | httpd      
       588)     pidgin recommends gstreamer1.0-plugins-good   
       589)     pidgin recommends pidgin-libnotify 
       590)     thunar recommends xfce4-panel (>= 4.11)       
       591)     thunar recommends xfce4-panel (< 4.13)        
       592)     thunar recommends thunar-volman    
       593)     wine1.6-i386:i386 recommends libfontconfig1:i386 | libfontconfig:i386    
       594)     wine1.6-i386:i386 recommends libsane:i386     
       595)     zenmap recommends gksu     
       596)     backbox-desktop recommends xfce4-mailwatch-plugin     
       597)     setoolkit recommends ettercap-common          
       598)     backbox-documentation-reporting recommends gtk-recordmydesktop   
       599)     backbox-documentation-reporting recommends zim
       600)     backbox-core recommends cups       
       601)     backbox-core recommends cups-bsd   
       602)     backbox-core recommends cups-client
       603)     backbox-core recommends cups-filters          
       604)     backbox-core recommends gucharmap
       605)     backbox-core recommends hplip
       606)     backbox-core recommends kerneloops-daemon
       607)     backbox-core recommends light-locker
       608)     backbox-core recommends pavucontrol
       609)     backbox-core recommends printer-driver-c2esp
       610)     backbox-core recommends printer-driver-foo2zjs
       611)     backbox-core recommends printer-driver-ptouch
       612)     backbox-core recommends printer-driver-pxljr
       613)     backbox-core recommends printer-driver-splix
       614)     backbox-core recommends xfce4-indicator-plugin
       615)     winetricks recommends zenity | kdebase-bin
       616)     libqtgui4 recommends libcups2]
       617)     libkhtml5 recommends kdelibs5-plugins (= 4:4.14.35-1)
       618)     kde-runtime recommends upower
       619)     libsolid4 recommends upower
       620)     libkopete4 recommends kopete (= 4:16.08.1-3)  
       621)     kdelibs5-plugins recommends kde-runtime
       622)     phonon-backend-gstreamer recommends gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
       623)     libqt5gui5 recommends qt5-gtk-platformtheme
       624)     libkio5 recommends kdelibs5-plugins (= 4:4.14.35-1)


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

for aptitude -f :

```
trys34e@trys34e:~$ sudo aptitude -f install
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

for  `apt-cache policy libkrb5-3:amd64 libkrb5-3:i386` ;

```
trys34e@trys34e:~$ apt-cache policy libkrb5-3:amd64 libkrb5-3:i386
libkrb5-3:
  Installed: 1.15.1-2
  Candidate: 1.15.1-2
  Version table:
 *** 1.15.1-2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2 500
        500 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1.13.2+dfsg-5 500
        500 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libkrb5-3:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2
  Version table:
     1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2 500
        500 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
     1.13.2+dfsg-5 500
        500 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your system `32bit` or `64bit`?

Comment: Run aptitude interactively, and try to find out where the dependencies are hung up. Sometimes you have to *remove* other packages so that new variants of this package with a different name can be installed.

Comment: @george amd64 sir

Comment: @dirkt Same problem in interactive mod, It wants delete 600 packages

Comment: Of course it will be the same problem in interactive mode. The point is to *find out* where the problem is. Which means you must inspect dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system is thoroughly messed up: you’ve somehow got a mixture of Ubuntu Xenial and Debian testing (or unstable even). However, your repositories don’t include the latter (which is a good thing). When installing 32-bit dependencies alongside 64-bit dependencies, the package manager needs to install versions which match the installed versions exactly; in your case for example, `libkrb5-3` 1.15.1-2 is installed, so it needs that version of `libkrb5-3:i386`, which it can’t find...

If you want to run Ubuntu, you should stick to Ubuntu, and avoid introducing packages from other distributions. To fix your problem, you *could* try to downgrade all the non-Ubuntu packages, but it would be safer to reinstall Ubuntu at this point (without restoring your packages from backup).

Comment: only 'apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop' or reinstall it completely?

Comment: Reinstall it completely (after copying any data you want to keep of course).